# Enabling pdo_mysql.so in WSL Ubuntu on PHP 8.0.5

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

First of all let me thank you for any answer in advance! Please be kind to me, this is my first post...

I'm currently very desperate. I'm trying to enable the pdo_mysql extension in PHP 8.0.5 on WSL Ubuntu 20.04 running under Windows 10 Pro. I tried every tip and really gotten forward so far, but I can't get beyond the error message: "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"... I checked everything, the path is alright, the file exists and still I am getting this error. I even went that far to hard code the path in the php.ini file. No dice.

Maybe you have an idea? Please let me know, I'm desperate.

Thank you for reading this, any tips are much appreciated!

Kind regards,
Florian

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the cli...
[Screenshot of the CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73SEn.png)

Comment: check this answer. It will help you fix your problem.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/999999/php-with-pdo-mysql-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I followed the instructions given in the link. Still not working....

Comment: Your best chance is to get a reliable third-party repository and handle everything with `apt`. If you start hacking things manually, things will go havoc sooner or later.

Comment: I found that I had

extension=pdo_mysql
uncommented in my php.ini file and this was causing the problem. Libraries are loaded by the files in the /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/ file on my system and don't need to be loaded by uncommenting lines in the php.ini file. But it isn't solving my problem... So back to square one 

Comment: That suggests you already have to tweaks aside from apt. Is it possible to remove everything, ensure you don't have old settings, and start over?